What is this literary device called where a quote is changed for comedic effect?
A direct quote from the Bible is changed for comedic effect. Is it an allusion? maybe a  paronomastic pan?

And God said: “Let there be cake. And there was cake. And God saw that it was good.”


I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about writing as defined in the help center.

This is called a parody.

This is a snowclone.  This is a relatively new term, though, and may not be widely known.

Are you suggesting until relatively recently. there was no term for it? That is, is 'snowclone' a replacement for something which went before?

@RobbieGoodwin  I have never heard a previous term for it.

What about Ben's 'parody', which struck me as wholly fitting?

@RobbieGoodwin Parody encompasses much more than this.

Thanks Mary and for myself, I thought both that valske's offering was a fine example of one kind of parody, and that it can't have languished nameless until someone started throwing snowclones.

I don't think it fits in a single rhetorical technique or literary device.  It can be interpreted as an example of multiple techniques
Since the original phrase is serious and carries great import, the substitution of cake for comedic effect seems like it makes this an example of Bathos, which its used to describe making either the silly serious or the serious silly.
It could also be 'defamiliarization' because the cake phrase is a transformation of something we are familiar with and flips it around.
